# get many-to-many from interface

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class Program with several many to many relationships like Age, Color... All these many to many properties inherit from an interface IFilter.

If I have an instance of the IFilter, how do I go on to call the below function for age or color?

```
ProgramList.CountByFilter(xxxMyFilterxxx, Filter.ID);

public static int CountByFilter(this IEnumerable<Program> ProgramList, Func<Program, IEnumerable<IFilter>> func, int ID)
{
         return (from x in ProgramList
                .Where(y => func.Invoke(y).Any(f => f.ID == ID))
                select x).Count();  
}
```

EDIT:

Sorry, what I meant is how can I do any of these calls:

```
ProgramList.CountByFilter(x => x.Ages, Filter.ID)
ProgramList.CountByFilter(x => x.Colors, Filter.ID)
```

When I don't know the object that I have on Filter - something like:

```
ProgramList.CountByFilter(x => x.IFILTER, Filter.ID)
```

but that obvioulsy won't work

Comment: Many-to-many relationships apply to databases, not to objects. How are `Program`, `Age` and `Color` declared?

Comment: How is the `IFilter` interface declared, and which objects implement it?

Comment: Age and Color implement IFilter

Comment: Why are you using an Expression?

Comment: @foson, is there another way of making the query dynamic so I can do: from x in ProgramList where x.Ages  -  or from x in ProgramList where x.Colors ?

Comment: You can just pass in a Func or an IEnumerable.  Expressions are only useful if you will modify the expression tree, (like LINQ to SQL)

Comment: @foson thanks that worked - I didn't realiase I didn't ned an expression. Btw did you see my last edit? any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: The question is still a little unclear.  Please add the code for the IFilter interface

Answer (score 1):

From the question, I assume Filter has an ID property.

This is an AND condition

```
    public static int CountByFilters(this IEnumerable<P> ProgramList, Expression<Func<P, IEnumerable<IFilter>>> exp, int[] ids)
    {
        var c = exp.Compile();
        HashSet<int> i = new HashSet<int>(ids);

        return (from x in ProgramList
                let filters = c.Invoke(x).Select(f => f.ID)
                where i.IsSubsetOf(filters)
                select x).Count();

    }
```

where `i.Any(f => filters.Contains(f))` could be an OR condition

Passing in filter IDs seems messy.  You may want to look into rearchitecting this.   Can't say what the performance is going to be like without knowing more about the collections.

If IFilter contained a member to evaluate if a program matches the filter, the code would be simpler:

```
public interface IFilter
{
    public Func<Program,bool> Matches { get; }
}

    public static int CountByFilter(this IEnumerable<P> ProgramList, IEnumerable<IFilter> filters)
    {
        return (from p in ProgramList
                where filters.Any(f => f.Matches(p))  //or All
                select p).Count();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> *how do I go on to call the below function for age or color?*

Something like this:

```
IFilter filter1 = /*... obtain an instance of IFilter (based on Age?) */;
IFilter filter2 = /*... obtain an instance of IFilter (based on Color?) */;

ProgramList.CountByFilter(program => new IFilter[] { filter1, filter2 }, Filter.ID);
```